# Can someone please explain why I am getting this compilation error?

Tags: java, generics

[image]

As per my understanding, `Predicate<? extends Integer>` means that this Predicate works with any type that is Integer or its subclass so, not sure why this is complaining. NOTE that doing something similar with first param `Collection<? extends Integer>` seem to be working as expected.
EDIT - Adding code as requested by others, also changed the type to Number as Integer doesn't have a subclass
`

```
public <T extends Collection<? extends Number>> int countSpecial(Collection<? extends Number> input, Predicate<? extends Number> p){
        int count = 0;
        for(Number i : input){
            if(p.test(i)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

`

Comment: Can you : 1) Copy the source code instead of giving us an image. 2) Returns the message depicting what the compiler is complaining about? Thanks.

Comment: exactly it also works with any TYPE that is a subclass of `Integer`, but `Integer` is not an instance of any subclass of `Integer`, disregarding that `Integer` is `final` and has no subclasses. Maybe a different example would be better. Assume `Predicate<? extends Animal>`, which, can also stand for `Predicate<Dog> p`. Now should it be allowed to call `p.test(cat);` with `Animal cat = new Cat()`? `p` is expecting a `Dog`  ((BTW this question is not a first time on StackOverflow))

Comment: You're right user16320675, see my response to Andy Turner's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding, `Predicate<? extends Integer>` means that this Predicate works with any type that is Integer or its subclass

No - it means the `Predicate` works with *a specific* subclass of `Integer`, or subclasses of that class. Since the compiler doesn't know which specific subclass of `Integer` is acceptable, it refuses to compile if you pass anything other than literal `null` to the `test` method.

---

`Integer` is a poor class to explain this with because it has no subclasses. But let's say it did:

```
class ChildOfInteger extends Integer {
  boolean foo() { return true; }
}
```

You could define a `Predicate<ChildOfInteger>`, say:

```
Predicate<ChildOfInteger> pCoi = ChildOfInteger::foo;
```

This invokes the `foo` method on the argument passed in - so clearly the compiler should try to stop you passing it anything that isn't a `ChildOfInteger`.

But a `Predicate<ChildOfInteger>` is also a `Predicate<? extends Integer>`:

```
Predicate<? extends Integer> pI = pCoi;
```

If you were allowed to pass an `Integer` to a `pI`, the `Predicate` wouldn't know what to do, because there's no `foo` method to invoke on it.

The compiler doesn't know if the `Predicate<? extends Integer>` refers to a `Predicate<Integer>`, a `Predicate<ChildOfInteger>`, or a `Predicate<ChildOfChildOfInteger>` etc. Hence, you can't invoke `test` on it, passing anything that's not provably `null` (`null` is allowed because it can be cast to any type without an exception being raised).

---

If you want to be able to pass in a `Predicate` that accepts `Integer` (or a subclass), but isn't specific to `Integer`, use `super`:

```
Predicate<? super Integer>
```

This means that it accepts a specific type - again unknown exactly - but `Integer` is a subclass of that, so it's acceptable to pass an `Integer` (or a subclass of `Integer`) to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I dug up more into java generics documentation and found this and it explains why I was getting the error (exactly. what you explained in your answer) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Integer` is a `final class` meaning it does not make sense to talk about subclasses to `Integer` as there aren't any. That out of the way, there are two ways to achieve what I believe is the desired effect.

### 1. Not using generics

A list of Integers will allow you to add instances of subclasses to the Integer class (which once again do not exist). This would look something like this:

```java
public int countSpecial(Collection<Integer> input, Predicate<Integer> p) {
    int count = 0;
    for(Integer i : input) {
        if(p.test(i)) {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

### 2. Not using wildcards

This will allow you to utilise the benefits of generics while still being able to achieve the desired effect - and I think this is what you were trying to do. It would look something like this:

```java
public <T extends Integer> int countSpecial(Collection<T> input, Predicate<T> p) {
    int count = 0;
    for(T t : input) { // t will be an instance of an Integer or an Integer subclass (which doesn't exist)
        if(p.test(i)) {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```